# How should I create a portable usb that updates an encrypted cloud backup whenever it can?

Tags: usb, backup, encryption, git-annex

I have a USB drive with all my code on it. I would like to have it auto-sync with a cloud service whenever I have Wi-Fi and it's plugged in. But only sync an encrypted version of the files. [Git Annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/workflow/) seems to have this, but git annex doesn't seem to be a good solution for lots of tiny files, only big ones.

Answer (score 0):

git-annex encrypts file with the [gcrypt git remote](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt) so you may want to look into that if you don't want to use git-annex directly. you could also tell git-annex to not checkin any files into git-annex and commit them to git instead, while keeping the inventory and sync features as well.